# Custom authentication issues

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, authentication, redirect

I'm implementing a custom authentication in ASP.NET MVC, and I'm having issues redirecting to the login/register page if the user isn't logged in.

I'm using a global variable for `IsAuthenticated`, and if this is false I want to redirect **all** requests to the `Account/LoginIndex` controller. I don't want to violate DRY and add a filter or basic check in all the controllers, so is there an entry point where I can redirect to the action is the boolean evaluates to false? How would I do this? I had a look at ActionFilters but I don't know where I'd add it as an attribute. I also looked at filters AND modifying the global.asax file. None of this works. The controllers rely on the user being logged in (otherwise it's error central), so how would I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Global filters and register AuthorizeAttribute as shown below

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
}
```

Then in your controller that deals with login you should override Authorization Filter so that it does not require authorization

```
[OverrideAuthorization]
public class AccountController : Controller
```

You can also implement a custom class that inherits from AuthorizeAttribute if you need any custom behavior for authorization and then register the custom class through global filters.